# Python Tkinter - Extend Scrollbar from East to West Border of the Frame Canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas

I have a canvas named `self.canvas_input_frame` with a canvas within called `self.canvas_input_image`. `self.canvas_input_image` is where the image is actually displayed. I have attached a child element vertical and horizontal scrollbars to `self.canvas_input_frame`. My GUI looks like the image below:

[image]

The horizontal scrollbar does not extend from west to east completely. How to fix it? Below is my code:

```
 def open_file_dialog(self):

    self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "C:/Users/alyss/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Damaged Text Document Virtual Restoration", title = "Select A File", filetype =  (("png", "*.png"),("jpeg", "*.jpg"),  ("pdf", "*.pdf"), ))


    #Create Canvas Frame for Input Document
    self.canvas_input_frame = tk.Canvas(self.main_canvas,  bg = "blue")
    self.canvas_input_frame.configure(width=456, height=470)       
    self.canvas_input_frame.pack(side="left", padx=10,pady = 10)

    #Load Input Image
    load = Image.open(self.filename)      
    render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
    self.width, self.height = load.size

    self.canvas_input_image = tk.Canvas(self.canvas_input_frame,bg = "green") # how to render image in canvas
    self.canvas_input_image.configure(width=390, height=470)
    self.canvas_input_image.image = render
    self.canvas_input_image.create_image(0,0,anchor="nw",image=self.canvas_input_image.image)
    self.canvas_input_image.pack(side="left")


    self.vsb_canvas_input_frame = tk.Scrollbar( self.canvas_input_frame, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas_input_image.yview)
    self.hsb_canvas_input_frame  = tk.Scrollbar( self.canvas_input_frame, orient="horizontal", command=self.canvas_input_image.xview)
    self.canvas_input_image.config(yscrollcommand=self.vsb_canvas_input_frame.set,xscrollcommand=self.hsb_canvas_input_frame.set)
    self.vsb_canvas_input_frame.pack(side = "right", fill = "y")
    self.hsb_canvas_input_frame.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "x")        
    self.canvas_input_image.config(scrollregion = self.canvas_input_image.bbox("all"))
```

Comment: I think your issue is packing order, you have packed your `self.canvas_input_image` on `left`, so when you pack scrollbar at bottom, it cannot go below image.
Please share [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code if you can't solve the issue.

Comment: @Kamal -- Thank u, I tried editing the .pack thing and replacint it with self.canvas_input_frame.place(x=10,y =90). The issue still occurs. I will try to share a working code.

Comment: I would suggest to try canvas_input_frame packing as it is, and change the order of other elements as: 1) vsb_canvas_input_frame on 'right' 2) hsb_canvas_input_frame on 'bottom' 3) canvas_input_image on 'left'.

Comment: @Kamal - Wow, thank you. It worked. Changing the order does the thing. You can put your answer to the answer section, so that I can mark it as right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the issue is the order of packing widgets. If you change the order of packing the elements like below then it can get you expected view.

```
self.vsb_canvas_input_frame.pack(side = "right", fill = "y")
self.hsb_canvas_input_frame.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "x")
self.canvas_input_image.pack(side="left")
```

One way to understand `pack` method is that if you pack widget1 in 'left' then any other elements can only fit on its opposite side that is 'right'(not left, up or down). Similar logic applies for other sides as well..